# Converting a date/math formula in Excel into Numbers for Mac

Tags: iwork

I have a formula in Excel that subtracts a birth date from today's date and divides by 365 which gives the age in decimal format. Example below.

B4 is equal to birthday of 10/03/2011.
E4 is today's date.
The result is 2.73. My child is a little over 2 and 1/2.

=IF(B4>0,(E$4-B4)/365," ")

When I try to use this formula in Numbers for Mac, it gives me an error about comparing dates with numbers and so. I looked at DatedIF, TimeValue, and DateValue but couldn't figure out how to do it in Number.

Anyone know how I could get this formula to return a decimal value of 2.73 years of age?

Comment: Try using both numbers as strings and converting them to dates. Excel is probably thinking one is a date while the other one isn't.

Comment: @pnuts Sorry. I mean the Numbers application for Mac which is part of the iWork suite. It is Excel for the Mac.

Comment: @AlexandreSantos any guidance on how to do that. The dates are part of a form and are stored as 10/03/2011 and the other one is a NOW() formula.

Comment: @pnuts Thanks. My apologies about that.

Comment: cast `datetime` into `int` like `int(now())`?

Comment: http://office.microsoft.com/en-ca/excel-help/convert-dates-stored-as-text-to-dates-HP001162867.aspx    http://fiveminutelessons.com/learn-microsoft-excel/convert-text-value-date-excel

Comment: Ah, you mean Numbers. I thought that by Number you meant a cell of the type number in Excel. Numbers. Got it.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming B4 is in "date" format, you could try the following formula

```
=IF(ISBLANK(B4),"",YEARFRAC(B4,TODAY(),1))
```

[Here is some documentation on YEARFRAC from the horse's mouth](http://support.apple.com/kb/PH674?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US)

Try entering the formula

```
=B4>0
```

in a different cell, you will then encounter en error

> You can’t compare a date with a number because their data types are different.